# Use this keyword in static method of class

Tags: typescript, methods, static, undefined, this

```
export default class SpecialtyAPI {
  public static async getSpecialtyList(request: Request, response: Response): Promise<TResponseData> {

  public static async getSpecialtyData(request: Request, response: Response): Promise<TResponseData> {
    // skip...

    try {
      specialtyData.dateLog = await this.getDateLogData(projectId as string, specialtyList);
      specialtyData.members = await this.getMemberData(projectId as string, specialtyList);
      return { data: specialtyData };
    } catch (error) {
      throw new FinchException(ErrorCode.FIREBASE_INTERNAL_ERROR, error);
    }
  }

  private static async getDateLogData(projectId: string, specialtyList: Array<TSpecialty>): Promise<TDateLog> {
    // logic...
  }

  private static async getMemberData(projectId: string, specialtyList: Array<TSpecialty>): Promise<TMembers> {
    // logic...
  }
}
```

In above code, ths this.[method] is undefined. The specific error message like this:

```
{
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "message": "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getDateLogData')\n    at getSpecialtyData (file:///Users/squarezero/workspace/finch-lite-firebase/functions/lib/index.js:773:48)\n    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n    at async responseHandler (file:///Users/squarezero/workspace/finch-lite-firebase/functions/lib/index.js:1103:30)\n    at async file:///Users/squarezero/workspace/finch-lite-firebase/functions/lib/index.js:1160:13"
}
```

I really don't know the reason. Every method is static and included in same class(SpecialtyAPI).
But in anther case, I can use this keyword by same way with above code. This is codes of the another case.

```
export default class FirebaseRepository {
  public static async createDocument(documentPath: string, data: object = {}): Promise<void> {
    const documentRef = this.getReference(documentPath) as DocumentReference;
    await documentRef.set(data);
  }

  public static async getDocumentData(documentPath: string): Promise<DocumentData | null> {
    const documentRef = this.getReference(documentPath) as DocumentReference;
    const snapshot: DocumentSnapshot = await documentRef.get();

    if (snapshot.exists) {
      return snapshot.data();
    } else {
      throw new Error('Document is not existing');
    }
  }

  public static async updateDocumentData(documentPath: string, data: object, merge = true): Promise<void> {
    admin.firestore().doc(documentPath).set(data, { merge });
  }

  public static async updateMultipleDocumentData(documentPaths: string[], data: object[], merge = true): Promise<void> {
    if (documentPaths.length !== data.length) {
      throw new Error('Document Paths and Data Lengths must match');
    }

    await admin.firestore().runTransaction(async (transaction) => {
      const documentRefs = documentPaths.map((path) => this.getReference(path)) as DocumentReference[];

      const documents: DocumentSnapshot[] = await Promise.all(
        documentRefs.map(async (ref) => await transaction.get(ref))
      );

      documents.forEach((doc, index) => {
        if (!doc.exists) throw new Error(`Document at index ${index} does not exist.`);
      });

      documentRefs.forEach((ref, index) => {
        transaction.set(ref, data[index], { merge });
      });
    });
  }

  public static async getDocumentList(collectionPath: string) {
    const collection = this.getReference(collectionPath) as CollectionReference;
    const snapshot: DocumentData = await collection.get();
    const docList: string[] = [];

    snapshot.forEach((doc: DocumentData) => {
      docList.push(doc.id);
    });

    return docList;
  }

  public static async getCollectionGroupData(
    collectionGroupName: string,
    filters?: Array<{ fieldPath: string; opStr: WhereFilterOp; value: any }>
  ): Promise<Array<DocumentData> | null> {
    const db = admin.firestore();
    let query: Query<DocumentData> = db.collectionGroup(collectionGroupName);

    if (filters) {
      for (const filter of filters) {
        query = query.where(filter.fieldPath, filter.opStr, filter.value);
      }
    }

    const querySnapshot = await query.get();

    return querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
  }

  private static getReference(path: string): DocumentReference<DocumentData> | CollectionReference<DocumentData> {
    let reference: FirebaseObjReference = admin.firestore();
    const tokens: string[] = path.split('/');

    for (const token of tokens) {
      if (tokens.indexOf(token) % 2 === 1) {
        reference = this.getDocumentRef(reference as CollectionReference<DocumentData>, token);
      } else {
        reference = this.getCollectionRef(reference as DocumentReference<DocumentData>, token);
      }
    }

    return reference as DocumentReference<DocumentData> | CollectionReference<DocumentData>;
  }

  private static getCollectionRef(
    documentRef: DocumentReference<DocumentData>,
    id: string
  ): CollectionReference<DocumentData> {
    return documentRef.collection(id);
  }

  private static getDocumentRef(
    collectionRef: CollectionReference<DocumentData>,
    id: string
  ): DocumentReference<DocumentData> {
    return collectionRef.doc(id);
  }
}
```

I know that using SpecialtyAPI instead of this is work. But I can't find the reason why "this" keyword is wrong.

what is differences about these two case.

I already used class name instead of this keyword. And check that worked.

Comment: Where and how do you use `getSpecialtyData()`?

Comment: `this` refers to an instance of a class. While the class name refers to the class itself.

Comment: @Reyno `this` can be used to call another static method from a static method. In the case of `static` methods, `this` refers to the class itself.